# Strange cursor bug on screen connected with USB to HDMI Adapter

Tags: cursor, mouse-cursor

I connected two screens to my notebook. One with HDMI over a USB-C docking station, the other one with an HDMI-USB 3.0 Adapter. On the screen which is connected with the USB Adapter a strange cursor bug appears. The cursor appears bigger and when the cursor symbol is changing to the waiting symbol it stays in addition to the original cursor symbol. This behavior is illustrated in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2F3g.jpg). Additionally, the symbol is randomly changing its colors to the ones of the background, which can be seen in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXCUy.jpg).

The cursor appears to be normal on the other external and the notebook screen. When plugging the other screen to the Adapter the issue jumps to the other screen. So the issue is connected to the Adapter. Windows mouse/cursor settings are all set correctly. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Could anybody help me with this specific issue? Is this maybe a driver problem? I am looking forward for any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, likely DisplayLink drivers. Update it if available. Nothing else to do.

Comment: DisplayLink driver is up to date. After deinstalling, the device is installing the driver automatically again. The problem stays. Is there any way to install different drivers?